# How to printf() only the first part of a string

Tags: c, ip, printf, cut

I have written a small program in C to get IP from remote user who log into SSH session

Code :

```
int main (){
    char * getIP ;
    getIP = getenv ("SSH_CLIENT");
    printf ("%s", getIP);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It works great and on output I have

```
shell# ./a.out
```

192.168.1.33 39840 22

But I would like to print only the IP address and not the rest of the string. I can't figure out how cut the string to print only the first part (255.255.255.255)

I search whole day solution but without success :/

Thanks for any help : )

**UPDATE !**

I discovered that instead SSH_CLIENT you can use REMOTEHOST : )
But Larsks solution is very helpful and worth remembering

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, what makes you think that there will be `REMOTE_ADDR` variable?  This is ssh, not Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `strtok()` to do this, since all you care about is the first string of characters before a space.  Use `strchr()` to locate the first space, set it to `NUL`, and you're done:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char *getIP, *mark;
    int i;
    getIP = getenv ("SSH_CLIENT");

    // get the location of the first space character
    mark = strchr(getIP, ' ');

    // set it to 0 (ascii NUL)
    *mark = 0;
    printf ("%s\n", getIP);
    return 0;
}
```

You could actually collapse it a little bit by doing this:

```
*(strchr(getIP, ' ')) = 0;
```

Instead of:

```
mark = strchr(getIP, ' ');
*mark = 0;
```

But that's not quite as clear, and it would be harder to do proper error checking.

Comment: Larsks thanks !  Your answer save my day : ). No i go read about strchr because i never use this function.

Comment: -1 you test not for an other separator-char than ' ', e.g. '\t'; you test not for NULL-return; also you should look at the standard: *The application shall ensure that it does not modify the string pointed to by the getenv() function.*

Comment: `printf("%.*s\n", strchr(getIP, ' ') - getIP, getIP);` prints the IP address without modifying any state. You may also consider adding error checking for strchr to make sure the environment variable actually contains a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can take apart the string returned by `getenv()` using `strtok()`, splitting the string on  spaces. The first token you get is the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** change the getenv-result

```
int main() {

  char firstword[BUFSIZ], *getIP = getenv("SSH_CLIENT");
  if( getIP )
  {
    sscanf( getIP , "%*s", BUFSIZ-1, firstword );
    puts(firstword);
  }
    return 0;
}
```